# iphone md5 generates different string as generated by Ruby on Rails

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, md5, digest

My iphone code donot generate same hex-string as generated by Ruby on Rails.

**My Ruby Code:**

```
hash = Digest::MD5.digest('aaa')  
hexMd5FromRuby = Digest::MD5.hexdigest( hash)
```

**iPhone Code:**

```
NSString *inStr = @"aaa";  
const char *cStr = [inStr UTF8String];  
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];  
CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );  

NSString *hexMd5FromIphone = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",  
result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6],
result[7],result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11], result[12], result[13],
result[14],result[15] ];
```

Both hexMd5FromRuby and hexMd5FromIphone generates different results.

Answer (score 2):

The correct MD5 is `47bce5c74f589f4867dbd57e9ca9f808`. Which one is wrong, the Ruby one? I don’t know Ruby, but it seems like you’re computing the hash twice in your example. This code works for me:

```
require 'digest/md5'
digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("aaa")
puts digest # 47bce5c74f589f4867dbd57e9ca9f808
```

Your code seems to get the binary digest of the string and then compute the hex MD5 digest of the binary data from the first step.